# Can't seem to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I've been spending a few hours trying to understand sessions and I can't seem to get logged in. I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

*Application Controller*

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
helper_method :current_user

def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def authorize
 redirect_to '/' unless current_user
end
```

*Session Controller*

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
   session[:user_id] = user.id
   redirect_to '/'
  else
   redirect_to '/sessions/new'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to '/'
 end
end
```

*User Controller*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @user = User.all
 end

 def new
  @user = User.new
 end

 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save!
   redirect_to '/'
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 def show
 end

 def edit
 end

 def update
  if @user.update
   redirect_to '/'
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def destroy
  @user.destroy
  redirect_to '/'
 end

 private
  def find_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :password, :about_me)
 end
end
```

*Sessions/new*

```
<%= form_tag('/sessions', method: "POST") do %>
 Email: <%= email_field_tag :email %>
 Password: <%= password_field_tag :password %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

*Routes*

```
root 'users#index'

resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users
```

If there are additional code that would be required please let me know. Also if you know a better convention in order to add login for my user, I'm open to learn different ways. Thank you for everyone help in understanding this problem.

Comment: can you expose user model?

Comment: for authentication you can use devise or clearance gem

Comment: @uzaif Thank you for replying. My user model is currently empty. The only thing I have in there is has_secure_password. Although devise would be simple and quicker, I want to learn/understand how to create a login from scratch.

Comment: can you help me for debug code which you written?

Comment: update this `params[:email]` to `params[:session][:email]` may be this will solve your issue

Comment: @uzaif After adding. The current error that I get when trying to log in is: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for   def create
    @user = User.where(email: params[:session][:email]).first

Comment: can you show me your params data when you submit form?